# Using UISwitches as radio buttons on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, radio-button, uiswitch

In my application i need the user to choose between 4 types of filters. If he chooses one filter the rest should close. When starting the application 1 type of filter is preselected. To choose a filter i am using UISwitches. At every time 1 and only 1 switch should be on. Never all closed and never more than one.

To make this work i am using 4 UISwitches. My code looks something like this:

```
- (IBAction)noFilterButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if([noFilterButton isOn]){
        [noFilterButton setOn:YES animated:YES];
        [filterByTopicButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [filterByDateButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [filterByDistanceButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
    else [noFilterButton setOn:YES animated:YES];

}

- (IBAction)filterByTopicButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if([filterByTopicButton isOn]){
        [noFilterButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [filterByTopicButton setOn:YES animated:YES];
        [filterByDateButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [filterByDistanceButton setOn:NO animated:YES];    
    }
    else [filterByTopicButton setOn:YES animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)filterByDateButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if([filterByDateButton isOn]){
        [noFilterButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [filterByTopicButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [filterByDateButton setOn:YES animated:YES];
        [filterByDistanceButton setOn:NO animated:YES];    
    }    
    else [filterByDateButton setOn:YES animated:YES];    
}

- (IBAction)filterByDistanceButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if([filterByDistanceButton isOn]){
        [noFilterButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [filterByTopicButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [filterByDateButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [filterByDistanceButton setOn:YES animated:YES];    
    }
    else [filterByDistanceButton setOn:YES animated:YES];
}
```

The code works pretty well. If you press a switch that is already on , the switch goes on again (actually goes off for half a second and then on automatically). If you press another switch then its turned on and all the rest off. The problem is that while testing the application i noticed that if i press a switch and instantly press another switch too they can both turn ON! I think this happens because with this code when you hit a switch thats already on it goes off and on again but while this "action" happens if you hit another switch they both "think" that should turn on. How can i make sure that at all times only 1 switch is on? I dont know if theres a way when a switch is on and you hit again , not to switch off and on , but just not "react" to the action. And even if there is , is it a solution that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)filterByDateButtonTapped:(id)sender 
{
    if(![filterByDateButton isOn])
        [filterByDateButton setOn:YES animated:YES];

    if([noFilterButton isOn])
        [noFilterButton setOn:NO animated:YES];

    if([filterByTopicButton isOn])
        [filterByTopicButton setOn:NO animated:YES];

    if([filterByDistanceButton isOn])
        [filterByDistanceButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Obviously the other methods should look like this too.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: When i saw the code you posted i thought it would have the same results with mine. But amazingly it works! I cant understand the difference though! I dont understand why like before , it doesnt get mixed up? Maybe 2 "if" would "run" together and produce an unexpected result but no! I am testing it now for 5 minutes and amazingly only 1 picker is ON! However is this a 100% solid solution? Cause if for any reason this behave unexpectedly the app will crash BIG TIME! :p

Comment: Glad it works. Yes , it's a solid solution. It's basically the same thing you had but it checks in order to skip an action if it's not needed. Because that's what you asked for ...to not react if the switch is already on.

Answer (score 2):

A `UISwitch` is the wrong control for what you're trying to do. You should use a [`UISegmented`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807) control instead.

Comment: actually the right way "by apple" is to use a UIPicker but thats not what i am asking. I am trying to learn here and not use something that works. I know how i can just make it work. I just want to find an answer to this specific question. I believe is a great example on how code works and what segments of code can behave unexpectedly..

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is a lot of code, there is a better way (Other than UISegmented).

Create an array that contains all the switches

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *switches

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.switches = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: filterByTopicButton, noFilterButton, filterByTopicButton, filterByDistanceButton, nil];
}
...
```

Connect all the UISwitch to the same IBAction, and do it like this

```
-(IBAction)switchSwitched:(UISwitch *)sender{
    for (UISwitch *switch in self.switches)
        if (![switch isEqual:sender]) [switch setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

That's all, same effect and much less code